# Debug em C/C++ no Visual Studio Code não funciona (Linux Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debug, visual-studio-code

Eu uso o Visual Studio Code, e queria usar seu Debug em meus arquivos de C/C++. Existem poucos tutoriais BR de como configurar o debug do VS code pra Linux, ainda mais na linguagem que utilizo, e como sou novato com esse editor de texto, ando tendo dificuldades.

O problema ocorre depois de configurado, ele simplesmente abre o painel de play/stop do debug, porém passa direto dos breakpoints e não consigo depurar, também aparece a seguinte menssagem de erro ao utilizar o debug:

**Unable to open 'libc-start.c': File not found (file:///build/glibc-Cl5G7W/glibc-2.23/csu/libc-start.c).**

sou novato no VS Code e não sei utilizar direito esse Debug, pode ser que eu esteja fazendo algo errado. Não sei o que fazer e nem como proceder, se algúem puder me ajudar, desde ja agradeço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O meu Launch.json do VS Code esta assim:**

```
{

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/draft",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tenta colocar stopAtEntry: false e exterlConsole:false

Pra mim isso não funciona mas pra você as vezes da certo.

Comment: Por favor, adicione mais detalhes para expandir sua resposta, como um código que funcione ou citações de documentação.